# Coco style dataset: Custom collate_fn function in Dataloader

Tags: pytorch, yolo, pytorch-dataloader, mask-rcnn

I have a coco style dataset and struggling to code the dataloader, in which `Dataset` class is the same as [this code](https://github.com/multimodallearning/pytorch-mask-rcnn/blob/809abba590db89779ac02c42286135f18ea08b53/model.py#L1308) and `__getitem__` returns the same outputs in the link (images, image_metas, rpn_match, rpn_bbox, gt_class_ids, gt_boxes, gt_masks)

When I am trying to load with pytorch default `collate_fn` I am getting the following error:

```
# Parameters for Dataloader
params = {'batch_size': 8,
          'shuffle': True,
          'num_workers': 4}
val_set = Dataset(dataset_val, config, augment=True)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_set, **params)
batch = next(iter(val_loader))
RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [1] at entry 0 and [5] at entry 2
```

Then I tried to define the custom `collate_fn` according to  [this link](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/dataloader-gives-stack-expects-each-tensor-to-be-equal-size-due-to-different-image-has-different-objects-number/91941/7) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72859877/6494707):

```
def my_collate_fn(data):
     zipped = zip(data)
     return list(zipped)

val_loader = DataLoader(val_set, **params, collate_fn = my_collate_fn)
```

where I cannot get the correct items of batch, for example:

```
# Loop over epochs
for epoch in range(0,1): #max_epochs
    # Training
    for inputs in train_loader:
        # Transfer to GPU
        images = inputs[0]
        image_metas = inputs[1]
        rpn_match = inputs[2]
        rpn_bbox = inputs[3]
        gt_class_ids = inputs[4]
        gt_boxes = inputs[5]
        gt_masks = inputs[6]
```

where inputs[0] returns the first item of batch (including `images`, `image_metas`, `rpn_match`, `rpn_bbox`, `gt_class_ids`, `gt_boxes`, `gt_masks`) Not the images of all `8` items in the batch.

**How can I resolve this issue?** How to load the data correctly by `collate_fn`?

Comment: Assuming the input of your collate function `data` to be something like `[(A0, B0, ..., G0), (A0, B0, ..., G0), ..., (A7, ..., G7)]` (batch size 8), you should stack each element (those share same alphabet) and return them as a list.